# Pipelines and waitpid

Tags: c, pipe, waitpid

I've got a problem with my pipeline. I looked through the topics, but did not find anything for my problem.

My pipeline works fine, but I want to know when my children terminate. So I want to use waitpid to check my children. But that does not work.

My pipe:

```
int interpretiere_pipeline(Kommando k){

    int pipe1[] = { -1, -1 };
    int pipe2[] = { -1, -1 };

    int status, pid, laenge, i;
    Kommando command; 
    Liste l;

    i = 0;
    status = 0;
    laenge = k->u.sequenz.laenge;

    l = k->u.sequenz.liste;


    printf("Anzahl der Elemente der Pipe: %i!\n", laenge);

    while(i < laenge) {
        pipe2[0] = pipe1[0];
        pipe2[1] = pipe1[1];
        command = (Kommando) listeKopf(l);

        if (i > 0) {
            close(pipe2[1]);
        }

        if (pipe(pipe1) < 0) {
            perror("Pipe-Fehler");
            exit(1);
        }
        /* fuehre Kindprozesse aus -> speichere pid */
        pid = fork();

        switch (pid) {
        case -1:
            /* Fehler bei Fork -> Abbruch */
            perror("fork-Fehler");
            exit(1);
        case 0:
            /* Leseströme umlegen auf vorherigen Prozess (außer beim ersten Prozess) */
            if (pipe2[0] != -1) {
                if(dup2(pipe2[0], STDIN_FILENO) == -1){
                    perror("dup2 failed\n");
                    exit(1);
                }
            }

            /* Schreibströme umlegen auf nachfolgenden Prozess (außer beim letzten Prozess) */
            if (i < laenge - 1) {
                if(dup2(pipe1[1], STDOUT_FILENO) == -1){
                    perror("dup2 failed\n");
                    exit(1);
                }
            }

            /* fuehre Kommandos aus */
            interpretiere_einfach(command, 0);
            exit(1);
            break;
        default:
            /* schreibe Prozesse in die Struktur */
            printf("Name : %s\n",command->u.einfach.worte[0]);
            pGlobal = erzeugeProzess( pid, "test", "RUNNING");
            /* fuege Struktur in Liste ein */
            procTable = listeAnfuegen(procTable, &pGlobal);
            /* Zaehler fue while-Schleife*/
            i++;

            sleep(2);
            break;
        }
        l = listeRest(l);
    }

    return status;
}
```

My waitpid

```
          waitpid(pid, &kind_status, 0);
            if(WIFEXITED(kind_status)){
                printf("Kind mit der PID %d wurde beendet\n",pid);
                if (WEXITSTATUS(kind_status) == 0) {
                    /** setze status exit(0) */ 
                    /*printf("Kind erfolgreich\n");*/
                    p->status = "exit(0)";
                } 
                /* nicht erfolgreiche ausgeführt */
                else 
                {
                    /** setze status exit(1) */ 
                    /*printf("Kind nicht erfolgreich\n");*/
                    p->status = "exit(1)";
                }
            }
            else if(WIFSIGNALED(kind_status)){
                /*printf("Kind mit der PID %d wurde durch Signal abgebrochen. Signalnummer: %d\n",pid, WTERMSIG(kind_status));*/
                p->status = "signal";
            }
          i = listeLaenge(procTable);
          procTable = listeAnfuegen(procTable, p);
          /*procTable = listeAnfuegen(procTable, &pGlobal);*/
          if(listeLaenge(procTable) <= i) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Fehler beim Schreiben in die Liste!");
          }
```

can I place it under my pipe in a loop with the length of the pipe?

Comment: You might consider having the parent monitor for SIGCHLD to know when the child(ren) terminate.

Answer (score 0):

How ever you do it, you have to store all child pids in some kind of list. So I would suggest, you do a loop like:

```
while( /* there are processes to be waited for */ ) {
    pid_t deadpid = waitpid( -1, &kind_status, 0 );
    /* handle kind_status and remove deadpid from the list */
}
```